# Calculated expression in Union Query (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I created a `UNION ALL` to join "year-over-year" totals by customer of sales data. The current month and year are obtained from the user and passed to the query and I get columns of customers, this year sales (CY) and last year sales (PY). It all works.

Now I want to add a calculated *difference* column. Here is my code showing the expression in the `SELECT` statement(s):

```
SELECT
   IIF(CY.Cust <> "", CY.Cust, PY.Cust) AS Cust,
   CY.CurSales AS CurSales,
   PY.PriSales AS PriSales,
   PY.PriSales - CY.CurSales AS Diff 
FROM
   (SELECT
         [Unique] AS Cust,
         SUM(Amount) AS CurSales 
      FROM
         Sales_Data 
      WHERE
         (Month <= Forms!SalesInput!MonthNum AND 
          [Sales_Data]![Year] = Forms!SalesInput!Year)
      GROUP BY
         [Unique]
   ) AS CY 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT
            [Unique] AS Cust,
            SUM(Amount) AS PriSales 
         FROM
            Sales_Data 
         WHERE
            (Month <= Forms!SalesInput!MonthNum AND 
             [Sales_Data]![Year] = Forms!SalesInput!Year-1)
         GROUP BY
            [Unique]
      ) AS PY 
   ON (CY.Cust = PY.Cust) 

UNION ALL

SELECT
    IIF(CY.Cust <> "", CY.Cust, PY.Cust) AS Cust,
    CY.CurSales AS CurSales,
    PY.PriSales AS PriSales,
    PY.PriSales - CY.CurSales AS Diff 
FROM
   (SELECT
         [Unique] AS Cust,
         SUM(Amount) AS CurSales 
    FROM
        Sales_Data 
    WHERE
        (Month <= Forms!SalesInput!MonthNum AND 
         [Sales_Data]![Year] = Forms!SalesInput!Year)
     GROUP BY
        [Unique]
    ) AS CY 

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT
           [Unique] AS Cust,
           SUM(Amount) AS PriSales 
       FROM
           Sales_Data 
       WHERE
           (Month <= Forms!SalesInput!MonthNum AND 
           [Sales_Data]![Year] = Forms!SalesInput!Year-1)
       GROUP BY
           [Unique]
      ) AS PY 
    ON (CY.Cust = PY.Cust) 

   WHERE
      (CY.Cust IS NULL AND PY.Cust IS NOT NULL);
```

This works unless either `PY.PriSales = 0` OR `CY.CurSales = 0`. If either result is blank/empty/zero I do not get a result from my expression. I've looked for the solution here with no luck. Can anyone point out what I'm missing? I feel like it's got to be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be running the full outer join in MS Access and need to return non-NULL *Sales* columns, consider wrapping every *Amount* with `NZ()` before `SUM()` which will ensure at least zero is returned:

```
SUM(NZ(Amount)) AS ...
```

You may even be able to do so at top level

```
NZ(PY.PriSales) - NZ(CY.CurSales) AS Diff
```

By the way, consider saving your aggregate queries as stored queries (i.e., views) and reference them in larger union query for more compact, readable SQL:

```
SELECT
   IIF(CY.Cust <> '', CY.Cust, PY.Cust) AS Cust,
   CY.CurSales AS CurSales,
   PY.PriSales AS PriSales,
   NZ(PY.PriSales) - NZ(CY.CurSales) AS Diff 
FROM qryCYAgg AS CY 
LEFT JOIN qryPYAgg AS PY ON (CY.Cust = PY.Cust) 

UNION ALL

SELECT
    IIF(CY.Cust <> '', CY.Cust, PY.Cust) AS Cust,
    CY.CurSales AS CurSales,
    PY.PriSales AS PriSales,
    NZ(PY.PriSales) - NZ(CY.CurSales) AS Diff 
FROM qryCYAgg AS CY 
RIGHT JOIN qryPYAgg AS PY ON (CY.Cust = PY.Cust) 

WHERE (CY.Cust IS NULL AND PY.Cust IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you (and everyone) who jumped in to help me with this. Turned out to be pretty simple and I've added a new tool to the kit.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help. We all been there knocking our head on the wall while a simple answer is in easy reach. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, for `UNION` queries, the field type is determined by the top query. If that only returns `Null`, you get the wrong field type.

You can include a header row that never gets returned to set labels and field types.

```
SELECT "String field" As Cust, CDbl(1.1) As CurSales, CDbl(1.1) As PriSales, 1.1 As Diff
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE FALSE
UNION ALL
... your unadjusted union query
```

Note that I'm assuming the field type of those sales are of the type `Double`. You can use an alternate cast in the header if that's not true.

Allen Browne has written an alternative simple trick to ensure the field type [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/data-type-for-nulls-in-union-query.3638777/). It uses an `IIF` statement that always returns one option, but still influences the field type.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, however I'm still experiencing the problem after making this change.